# Unclear question on threshold probability

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I found this question:
Consider the binomial subset of $\Gamma = \{1,...,N\}$. Find a threshold probability for
containing a tuple $x<y<z$ such that $x + y = z$.

I am really confused about what the author means by the 'binomial subset' here. Could anyone please elaborate on the question? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The words "binomial subset" are pretty much nonsense, but from context, it's likely that the author meant: "Choose a subset of $\{1, 2, \dots, N\}$ by choosing each element independently at random with probability $p$."

A threshold probability means that we consider the limit as $N \to \infty$, letting $p$ depend on $N$. The threshold probability $p^*$, also depending on $N$, should satisfy the following:

- if $p \ll p^*$, the desired property (having a tuple $x<y<z$ with $x+y=z$) holds with a probability tending to $0$ as $N \to \infty$.
- if $p \gg p^*$, the desired property holds with a probability tending to $1$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But the problem seems very hard to me especially because of the condition that $x+y=z$. Could you provide any hints. Again thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Begin by estimating the number of such triples $(x,y,z)$. You don't have to get it exact; within a constant factor is fine.